# Constructor: set this reference

Tags: java

I've an already implemented application which connects to a *database*. Now, the problem is that I need to implement a *caching system* (if easily possible) for some of the objects because their initialization takes too long for getting the needed data from the database every time when I need those objects. (Those objects won't change quite often and in fact, I could update them using a timestamp if necessary.)

Since I can't easily change the whole application I'd like to know if there is any method so that I can set the "this" object within the constructor itself. I am referring to the ability of Objective-C where I am able to call any method that returns an `id` and set it to the `self` "variable" which then updates in fact the whole object.
To explain my idea a bit better: I want to initialize a static cache in those classes and get the already stored object (if available) within the constructor. Please note that all *setters refer to SQL* code too.

I also know that I could just *use the getters* of the already stored object to set the values of the new one within the constructor but this would *create many objects* too and in case there might be a *change in the values I won't replicate* this to all other objects cloned from that one.

Any ideas, thanks?!

Comment: No, you can't change `this` in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constructor only operates on a new object.  If you want to reuse objects, you cannot use the constructor.  Creating the object itself is trivial << 100 ns which leads me to believe you don't need to recycle the object, but the data in the object which comes from the database.

Accessing a database is about 0.1 to 10 ms.  Creating an object is 10 to 100 ns (on millionth of a milli-second)  If you are concerned about the cost of creating new objects, you shouldn't be using a database at all as it could one million time more expensive.

Comment: Ok, thank you and yes using the database is really expensive because within those objects mostly many others need to be created too. I think I need to stick to just copy the existing data of those objects.